# DataGrid sorting doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, wpfdatagrid

I have a `TabControl` that has one `TabItem`with a `DataGrid` inside.

```
<TabControl Background="{DynamicResource StandardBackgroundColor}" 
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource StandardBorderColor}" 
            DataContext="{Binding ChartViewModel}">


<TabItem Header="{lex:Loc Data}">
           <DataGrid Name="TagGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding UnionAllSerie}" 
                     ColumnWidth="*" Background="#CCCCCC">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc time}" SortDirection="Descending"
                                            Binding="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource OleDateToDateTimeConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm\}}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc Measure}"
                                            Binding="{Binding Y}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
</TabItem>
```

Where my UnionAllSerie is declared as follow:

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> UnionAllSerie { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
```

This collection of data is populated depending on the action performed on the window. What I want is to have the `Grid` automatically sorted by the second column, which represents the date.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the SortDirection on a Datagrid column does not actually sort the column. (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vinsibal/2009/04/14/5-more-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid/) for details).

I would recommend using a CollectionViewSource which has build in functionality for your purpose.
The result should look something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="UnionAllSerieViewSource" Source="{Binding UnionAllSerie}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="X" Direction="Descending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid Name="TagGrid" ItemsSource=""{Binding Source={StaticResource UnionAllSerieViewSource}}"" 
                 ColumnWidth="*" Background="#CCCCCC">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc time}" SortDirection="Descending"
                                    Binding="{Binding X, Converter={StaticResource OleDateToDateTimeConverter}, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy HH:mm\}}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="{lex:Loc Measure}"
                                    Binding="{Binding Y}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

For more information on how to sort CollectionViewSources see [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742542(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Perfect! It works as wanted! Thanks for the articles.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) As it solved your problem would you consider accepting this answer?